# Whose Job is it to Display or Hide Push Notification on iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a beta app that people are testing. Some are saying that they "turned off" push notifications in the Settings app but they are still getting notifications. My assumption is that if the user turned off notifications for my app via the Settings app, then I could still send notifications to their device and the notifications would not be displayed.

Is there a problem with how I am handing this? I have been searching through the Push Notification documentation but haven't found anything about this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the users job to allow them.

It's the systems job to fetch/display them.

It's the servers job to send them.

Comment: So if the user turns off notifications in the Settings app and I keep sending notifications, that is not bad?

Comment: The APSFeedbackServer is there to tell you if you do bad. For the rest its fire and forget.